# can UserDefaults continue save new data after each .synchronize()?

Tags: ios, swift, synchronization, userdefaults

I wrote an app includes a main program A and an action extension B.

Users can use action extension B to save some data into UserDefaults. 
like this:

```
let defaults = UserDefaults(suiteName: "group.com.ZeKai")
    defaults?.set(self.doubanID, forKey: "doubanID")
    defaults?.set(self.doubanRating, forKey: "doubanRating")
    defaults?.set(self.imdbRating, forKey: "imdbRating")
    defaults?.set(self.rottenTomatoesRating, forKey: "rottenTomatoesRating")
    defaults?.set(self.chineseTitle, forKey: "chineseTitle")
    defaults?.set(self.originalTitle, forKey: "originalTitle")
    defaults?.synchronize()
```

Wating to transfer this data to main program A while A is opened.

But if I use action extension twice to save data like data1 and data2, then I open the main program A, only data2 is received by A, means always new data overwrite the new data in UserDefaults.

so, I would like to know whether I can save multiple data in UserDefaults, and they will be all transferred to main program A?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To save multiple data to `UserDefaults` you should use unique keys for that data. Also read about `synchronization`:

> Because this method is automatically invoked at periodic intervals,
>   use this method only if you cannot wait for the automatic
>   synchronization (for example, if your application is about to exit) or
>   if you want to update the user defaults to what is on disk even though
>   you have not made any changes.

If the data is descriptive as in case you describe. Try to use structures to represent models.

Example of the user `struct`:

```
public struct User {

    public var name: String

    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }

    public init(dictionary: Dictionary<String, AnyObject>){
        name = (dictionary["name"] as? String)!
    }

    public func encode() -> Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
        var dictionary : Dictionary = Dictionary<String, AnyObject>()
        dictionary["name"] = name as AnyObject?
        return dictionary
    }

}
```

Usage of the structures and `UserDefaults`.

```
let user1 = User(name: "ZeKai").encode()
let user2 = User(name: "Oleg").encode()

let defaults = UserDefaults(suiteName: "User")
defaults?.set(user1, forKey: "User1")
defaults?.set(user2, forKey: "User2")
defaults?.synchronize()

let user1EncodeData = defaults?.dictionary(forKey: "User1")        
let user = User(dictionary: user1EncodeData as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>)
```

Comment: @ZeKai you are weilcome

Comment: Calling `synchronize()` is no longer needed at all: "Waits for any pending asynchronous updates to the defaults database and returns; this method is unnecessary and shouldn't be used."